# Как получить reference код дороги в OSM?

Tags: api, openstreetmap, geocoding

Есть набор координат, например, 54.628035, 38.386937
Необходимо получить reference код (название дороги) 
Для заданного набора координат это Р29

Есть какие-то способы это сделать?